# No Option to Select Operating System - Stuck in Aptio Setup Utility - Please Offer Diagnosis

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi

I recently purchased an M1T Mini PC Desktop Computer Intel Celeron N4100 (I believe this is an SSD device) which came with pre-installed Windows 10. Within Windows 10 I adjusted the size of some partitions so as to install Ubuntu for dual boot. I installed Ubuntu Studio 20.04.2.0 LTS and followed steps for UEFI mode.

After installation everything worked fine on both Operating Systems however when restarting the machine went only to Aptio Setup Utility. I disabled secure boot and fast boot and after powering down the machine then booted as normal.

About a week later the grub menu no longer loaded at start up and the machine only loads the Aptio Setup Utility.

The machine runs the Live Ubuntu from USB without any problems. I am however, unable to re-install   as the Installation type screen is empty. I ran a Windows 10 USB but was unable to resolve the issue. Repair-Boot was unable to perform any changes and I include here the repair-boot file.

There appear to be a number of problems but as a beginner with extremely limited knowledge of computer terms and their meaning I am at a loss as to where to begin. I've spent time attempting to follow some of the similar question/answer guides here as well as in other forums, but as a beginner I'm rather out of my depth.

I am hopeful that I might gain your guidance in diagnosing the problem. I'm not concerned about losing Windows however I'd like to understand the cause, re-install Ubuntu and avoid a recurrence.

I greatly appreciate any time you spend offering diagnostic guidance. See Repair-Boot included:

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/tM9MJ93PGC/

Comment: I’m no expert on the boot repair output but it looks like the internal storage is not being detected. That also seems to be the case with the Windows and Ubuntu installers. You may have broken hardware. Do you know if you have onboard eMMC  storage or an m.2 ssd? Some people have fixed a similar issue here https://forums.tomsguide.com/threads/how-to-solve-problems-with-aptio-setup-utility.338366/

Comment: Thank you PonJar. It is M.2 interface support: M.2 2242 SSD. I had previously tried that forum however Aptio does not offer me a 'Launch CSM' option. Before I consider having a technician check for internal damage I would like to try and rule out the possibility of a configuration issue (within Aptio - especially given that it worked initially - I wonder if a restart could have changed some parameters), or even an Intel issue (as I have read on the Intel website of instances in which some SSDs were not being detected).

Comment: I’m not familiar with Aptio. Is there a function to reset to factory defaults or to restore the system (you might lose data if you restore) If that does not work have a look at any settings to do with storage.

Answer (score 2):

Please accept my apology for the late reply.

A technician took the device apart to test components and found the SSD defective.